# How to dependency to Android native code using CMake?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I am currently writing JNI code for an **Android application** to use some **legacy native code**. I chose to use **CMake** to give it a try (this is my first time using it).

I would like to serialize a quite complex C structure to JSON format using [Jansson](https://github.com/akheron/jansson) library. This would to make it more simple to expose it to Java.

Here is my question: **How is it possible to import Jansson in my project as a dependency for my own code ?**

I tried to import Jansson in my own sources and use a *add_subdirectory* clause to make it build. As a result, I can see some intermediates CMake files in the output but **no actual compiled file**.

Here is what my CMake file looks like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(
             src/main/cpp/xxx/Include
             )

add_subdirectory("src/main/cpp/jansson")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             # Associated headers in the same location as their source
             # file are automatically included.
             src/main/cpp/xxx/file1.c
             src/main/cpp/xxx/file2.c
             src/main/cpp/xxx/file3.c
             src/main/cpp/xxx/file4.c
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Any help will be welcomed !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I was just missing to declare the dependency of my library on Jansson. This is made by adding its project name to the existing *target_link_library* clause.

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       jansson
                       ${log-lib} )
```

In case someone else (well maybe my future self) stumbles on the same problem, here are **all the necessary steps to add a native dependency in an Android CMake file**:

- Find a library already supporting CMake
- Import library code in your project (I used git submodule)
- Add *add_subdirectory* clause that points to the folder containing the library CMake file
- Add include files to *include_directories* (hopefully, the imported library set a variable for that, such as JANSSON_INCLUDE_DIRS in my case
- Add dependency by adding the library project name to the *target_link_libraries* clause

Once this is done: poof ! magic ! everything works fine !